# how to configure ~/.gitconfig file instead of individual repo's .git/config file?

Tags: git

How to configure ~/.gitconfig file instead of individual repo's .git/config file?

```
## use this config if repository belongs to userA@github
[user]
        name = userA
        email = userA@gmail.com

## use this config if repository belongs to userB@github
[user]
        user: userB
        email: userB@yahoo.com 

## use this config if repository belongs to userC@bitbuck
[user]
        user: userC
        email: userC@hotmail.com
```

Comment: You can just edit `~/.gitconfig` (for each user A, B, C) with a text editor, although I think you probably mean `user.name`, not `user.user`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be:

- to have `userA`, `userB` and `userC` local account
- to clone each of the GitHub repo intheir respective local account
- to have global setting (`~userA/.gitconfig`, `~userB/.gitconfig`, `~userC/.gitconfig`) in place with the right user names and emails.

In that case, there would be no configuration required: any repo clone under `~userA` home directory would benefit from the right `user.name` and `user.email`.

But if you are trying to that automatically under *one local account, then you need to come up with some script which will create/update the right value in the *local* config file `~/repo/gitHubCloneRepo/.git/config`.